# Decoding OTP from totpSecret alike google authenticator

Tags: keycloak, google-authenticator, totp

I have a totpSecret generated from my keycloak application what I want to acheive is send user the decoded OTP for this I have already implemented the custom resource provider and obtained totpSecrect using that but what I get is a string and what I want is Otp code e.g. 123 456 like a google authenticator would do after providing the string totpSecretEncoded or after scanning the produced QR code. How can I decode the totpSecret to obtain the otp code? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how you obtained user totpSecrect ?

Comment: Oh! im very sorry for the late reply but i obtained the totp secret implementing the keycloak itself. the endpoint which is used by authenticator when looked upon in the json format you will find yourself with the TOTP secret which then upon decoding you will obtain the OTP.

Answer (score 0):

[TimeBasedOTP](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/9.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/models/utils/TimeBasedOTP.html) should be used in this case.

```
   String secret = "totpSecretEncoded";
   secret = new String(Base32.decode(secret));
   System.out.println(new TimeBasedOTP().generateTOTP(secret));
```